# Translation of select field allowed values

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a field that has just one option to choose. It's:

Online|This product will be delivered online

I'm struggeling to make it translatable, but with no luck. I've checked everywhere and I stucked. So, in database there is core locales_source table that holds english phrases. There is a source and context of this phrase:

```
lid: 39
location: field:field_product_delivery:#allowed_values:Online
textgroup: field
source: This product will be delivered online
context: field_product_delivery:#allowed_values:Online
version: 1
```

There is also locales_target table that contains translations and there is:

```
lid: 39
translation: Este producto se ofrece online
language: es
plid: 0
plural: 0
i18n_status: 1
```

Still, the value is displayed in English on Spanish node view page. 
How to force it to use correct translation, not the english phrase. By the way, my default language set in Drupal is Spanish.

Comment: try https://www.drupal.org/project/lingotek module, i't traslate's everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you enabled the *Field Translation* module, a submodule (i18n_field) of the [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module. Some more details about it (from the [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279346)):

> ... allows for translation of text associated with a field's settings including the label, help text, default value, and list options. Translation of these field settings can be added through the 'Translate interface' pages (`Administration > Configuration > Regional and language > Translate interface`).

Especially the "***list options***" mentioned above seem to be what you're looking for.